# Aliases in HiveQL

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm looking into [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Union) example

```
SELECT u.id, actions.date
FROM (
    SELECT av.uid AS uid
    FROM action_video av
    WHERE av.date = '2008-06-03'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ac.uid AS uid
    FROM action_comment ac
    WHERE ac.date = '2008-06-03'
 ) actions JOIN users u ON (u.id = actions.uid)
```

I guess `av`, `ac` and `u` are aliases. If so, why is `AS` not needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no mandatory to use as in alias,. If a table appears more than once in the FROM clause, you need table aliases in order to keep them distinct

```
SELECT u.id, actions.date
FROM (
    SELECT av.uid  uid
    FROM action_video av
    WHERE av.date = '2008-06-03'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ac.uid AS uid
    FROM action_comment ac
    WHERE ac.date = '2008-06-03'
 ) actions JOIN users u ON (u.id = actions.uid)
```